# I can't import React components with webpack

Tags: reactjs, import, webpack, components, require

in my project I have 2 main files "app.jsx" and "Layout.jsx". When I define my Layout component inside my "app.jsx", it renders successfully. But, when I move it to "Layout.jsx" and require it from "app.jsx" it doesn't work.
here is my code:

"Layout.jsx"

```
module.exports = class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <h3>Layout Component</h3>
        )
    }
}
```

"app.jsx"

```
const React = require("react");
const ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

const Layout = require("./pages/Layout.jsx");

const App = document.getElementById("app");
ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, App);
```

What's wrong in my code ?

Comment: what's the error you are receiving after moving to layout.jsx?

Comment: Webpack just bundles files successfully, but when I look into React debugging tool for Firefox I see the following message: "waiting for roots to load ... "

Comment: have you import react on your layout.jsx file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your layout.jsx file  you need to import

```
const React = require("react");
```